# Arch-linux: Emacs: exporting to html in org-mode and opening in external browser doesn't work

Tags: arch-linux, emacs

I created a test file 'test.org' to get into org-mode and wanted to export it to HTML and open it in the standard browser via C-c C-e h o. But instead of opening the browser the html code is sent to another buffer within emacs. So I guess, the code-export does work, but it is not directed to the external browser (don't know whether this is one function, though).

I've set the Browse-Url-Browser-Function explicitly to Chromium (and to Firefox) in the Options menu. (Options -> Customize Emacs -> Top Level Customization Group -> External -> Browse URL -> Browse Url Browser Function)

I've also pasted some configs I found on Google into .emacs and .emacs.d/init.el.

None of the above works.

With all the other "regular" distributions there doesn't seem to be a problem there and it just works out of box without any configurations.

Can an Arch user help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26881/9257. Org-mode uses `org-file-apps` to decide how to open a file. Use

```
(setq org-file-apps
    (quote
      ((auto-mode . emacs)
       ("\\.mm\\'" . default)
       ("\\.x?html?\\'" . "/usr/bin/firefox %s")
       ("\\.pdf\\'" . default))))
```

to override how Org-mode opens html files.